# Como testar requisições POST no "Postman" em locais que é necessário utilizar autenticação por sessão?

Tags: testes, postman

O Postman é o aplicativo embutido ao navegador Google Chrome que utilizo para testar minhas requisições em POST.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

Porém a área que desejo acessar só é acessível através de login e senha. No entanto, como não se trata de uma API REST ou nada similar, eu não implementei nenhum dos tipos de autenticação que são suportadas pelo aplicativo.

- No Auth
- Basic Auth
- Digest Auth
- OAuth 1.0
- OAuth 2.0 Hawk
- Authentication AWS Signature

Como eu poderia testar requisições POST sem necessariamente ter que desativar minha área protegida por login? Há um meio de realizar isso no POSTMAN ou há alguma alternativa melhor?

Answer (score -1):

Try this [link](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/helpers)

Ou, se estiver usando token... copie o token de seu codigo e adcione o no cabecalho(header):
Authorization: Bearer Token_String
(key: "Authorization" ; value: "Bearer Token_String" ) sem aspas... apenas para indicar a string

Answer (score -2):

**Observação**

1. Não use esse plugin do postman
2. Baixe o software do postman no site oficial

---

Se eu estiver certo, você criou uma tela de login apenas com campo e-mail e usuário e nada de token. Para acessar via postman, vai colocar os dados do e-mail e senha nessa parte da tela do post man.

[image: Tela sem Auth]
Tela sem o uso de algum tipo de Auth

[image]
Clica no **botão** params e colocar os dados do seu login

---

---

Na minha opinião, não tem sentido usar o postman para esse próposito. Já que ele foi desenvolvido para fazer testes de requisições de api e obter a resposta desses request.